# Painting signature translation (Characters identified: 筠新)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, transcription

Painting done in China in 1987 by local artist. I've asked many Chinese Nationals to translate, unfortunately no one could. I was always told that it is written in very ancient Chinese.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The characters are 「筠新」, which likely points to the artist 「雕筠新」 (Mandarin Pinyin: maybe **Diāo Jūnxīn**).

Here's another piece which features the same seal:  http://auction.zhuokearts.com/art/25922855.shtml